# Tableau - need to compare the number of records that came in last 7 days to the number of records that came in the last 7 days -1

Tags: compare, date-range, tableau-desktop

In Tableau I have a db containing records with a create date [create date]
I need to compare the number of records that came in last 7 days to the number of records that came in the last 7 days -1 .
And show the change as a percentage.

Thanks

Comment: please, explain better what "last 7 days - 1" means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming today is August 31th, last 7 days should be Aug 24-30, excluding today.

```
sum(if DATEDIFF('day',[Order Date],DATE(TODAY()-1)) <= 6  then 1 end )
```

If "7 days -1" means last 7 days starting from one day prior to yesterday, this second range is Aug 23-29.

```
sum(if DATEDIFF('day',[Order Date],DATE(TODAY()-2)) <= 6  then 1 end )
```

According to your different needs, you can just use this formula [(A/B)-1] in order to get the change in %:

```
(
sum(if DATEDIFF('day',[Order Date],DATE(TODAY()-1)) <= 6  then 1 end )
/
sum(if DATEDIFF('day',[Order Date],DATE(TODAY()-2)) <= 6  then 1 end )
)
-1
```

Comment: Thanks Fabio That works.
Why do i need the '-1' at the end?

Comment: example: first period 150 & second period 100; 150/100 = 1,5; 1,5-1= 0,5 = 50% change